# Mobile only accordion nav

Tags: jquery, css

I have a jsfiddle here - https://jsfiddle.net/810mp54o/26/

I dont like doing this but I have a working example but I'm sure there is a better way to do it.

I have a simple header with content underneath that I want to put into an accodion on mobile.

I'm using jquery to add a open class but I need to add !important t gte it to work - is thera better way to do this.

Also I know people would never resize the browser and this would either be seen on desktop or mobile but is there a way to always show the accordian as closed in the mobile sizes.

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('.js-btn').on('click', function(){
            $(this).next('.content').toggleClass('open');
        })
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, you could use somthing like navibar from bootstrap (https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_navbar&stacked=h)

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
      <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>

    <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">WebSiteName</a>
        </div>
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
          <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Page 1</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Page 2</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Page 3</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </nav>

    <div class="container">
      <h3>Basic Navbar Example</h3>
      <p>A navigation bar is a navigation header that is placed at the top of the page.</p>
    </div>

    </body>
    </html>
```